# Oracle sql delete query optimization

Tags: sql, optimization, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-delete

I am trying to optimize query which has delete functionality. Query contains multiple conditions with combination for deleting records.

```
 Delete from table1 where (trunc(date) ='4-Jan-2023' AND ID=12) OR (trunc(date) ='4-Jan-2023' AND ID=13) OR 
(trunc(date) ='4-Jan-2023' AND ID=12) OR 
.
.
.
.
.
(trunc(date) ='4-Jan-2023' AND ID=14);
```

Please give me solution for this.

I want to optimize this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're applying `trunc` function to `date` column (that's most probably not its true name, is it? `date` is a reserved word, reserved for datatype name), then - if there's an index on that column - it won't be used. Either create a function-based index:

```
create index i1_t1_datum on table1 (trunc(datum));
```

or switch to

```
where datum >= date '2023-01-04'
  and datum <  date '2023-01-05'
```

Also, you're forcing datatype implicit conversion so that `date` datatype value is compared to a string (`'4-Jan-2023'` is a  string).

As all date values are the same and `ID`s change, move them into `in` clause.

So, if you index columns involved into the `where` clause, gather statistics (on schema; if not, then - at least - on table and indexes) and use such a query, it might (or not) help:

```
delete from table1
where datum >= date '2023-01-04'
  and datum <  date '2023-01-05'
  and id in (12, 13, 14);
```

Consider explaining the statement so that you'd see what database really does.

Comment: There is py_date as date in query. And I need to delete combination of particular py_date and id records only. Thats why I wrote this query. And also I create function based index but it won't improve performance.

Comment: Delete from table1 where (trunc(py_date) ='4-Jan-2023' AND ID=12) OR (trunc(py_date) ='5-Jan-2023' AND ID=13) OR 
(trunc(py_date) ='14-Jan-2023' AND ID=12) OR 
.
.
.
.
.
(trunc(py_date) ='44-Jan-2023' AND ID=14);

Comment: Well, then that's THE query, I guess. I don't know what else you can do.

Comment: Is there any way in oracle to delete combination of records?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IN` with multiple values which will make your query easier to read:

```sql
DELETE FROM table1
WHERE (TRUNC(py_date), id) IN (
        (DATE '2023-01-04', 12),
        (DATE '2023-01-05', 13),
        (DATE '2023-01-14', 12),
        (DATE '2023-01-04', 14)
      );
```

However, if you are looking to be more efficient then you should use ranges for the dates:

```sql
DELETE FROM table1
WHERE DATE '2023-01-04' <= py_date AND py_date < DATE '2023-01-05' and id = 12
OR    DATE '2023-01-05' <= py_date AND py_date < DATE '2023-01-06' and id = 13
OR    DATE '2023-01-14' <= py_date AND py_date < DATE '2023-01-15' and id = 12
OR    DATE '2023-01-04' <= py_date AND py_date < DATE '2023-01-05' and id = 14;
```

and put a composite index on `py_date, id`.

Or you can use `TRUNC(py_date)` and a composite function-based index on `TRUNC(py_date), id`.